# WPF - Get size of UIElement in Memory?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, size, uielement

Is there a way to get the size of a `UIElement` that resides in memory and has not yet been rendered?

I currently have a routine that creates a `Grid` from a `DataTable` and then adds the Grid into a `FixedDocument`.  I need to know the size of the `Grid` because I want to automatically switch from Portrait to Landscape if needed; or even change the `FontSize` of the grid.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to force a render of the item, or wait for the item to be rendered. You can then use the `ActualHeight` and `ActualWidth` properties.

To force a render:

```
  MenuItem item = new MenuItem();
  item.Header = "bling";
  item.Icon = someIcon;
  //Force render
  item.Measure(new Size(Double.PositiveInfinity, Double.PositiveInfinity));
  item.Arrange(new Rect(item.DesiredSize));
```

In this example the `MenuItem` has not been given an explicit height or width. However, forcing the render will render it taking the supplied header text and icon into consideration.

Comment: `MenuItem` did not work for me, but `StackPanel` or `Viewbox` did.

Comment: There is no property called 'ActualWidth' on the class 'UIElement' :-(

Comment: Occasionally complex controls may not be correctly rendered if you have a lot of panels being hidden - this is what I had to do to work around it : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41966704/wpf-xaml-control-converted-to-an-image-has-incorrect-layout/41966743#41966743

Answer (score 1):

You can only determine this if there is an explicit `Width` or `Height` set.  Even then, depending on the scenario, it may change at render time, since the Layout pass will not occur until it's rendered, and `ActualWidth`/`ActualHeight` get set.

Comment: So my only option is to repeatedly render the control using differing font sizes and page layouts until it fits?

Comment: @Sonny: That, or render it to some other location... You could always use RenderTargetBitmap, etc, to try to render it "off screen" and then adjust, if you don't want to have the user see it...