# WPF Xaml control converted to an image has incorrect layout

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have a control that I am converting to an image using the method here :

[Force rendering of a WPF control in memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080375/force-rendering-of-a-wpf-control-in-memory)

Unfortunately I have a complex layout and it seems that a control being 'Collapsed' isn't actually being hidden properly in the output image.

Tried:

- Call `UpdateLayout` multiple times
- Change size of control by 1 pixel
- Using a ViewBox

It seems to affect DockPanel if something is aligned to the bottom and hidden with a converter.

```
<DockPanel LastChildFill=True>
    <Something Dock.Panel="Top" />
    <Something Dock.Panel="Bottom" Binding="{Binding XXXXX, Converter={StaticResource booleanConverter}}"/>
    <Something Dock.Panel="Bottom" Binding="{Binding YYYYY, Converter={StaticResource booleanConverter}}"/>
    <Something />
</DockPanel>
```

Everything displays just fine in the Xaml editor, or if it is used at runtime in a real visible control.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I had to use a trigger to set the height to zero instead of applying `Collapsed` to the elements. Of course this means any margins must be converted to padding,  with nested panels if needed.

In this instance I had a border control - so I had to remove the Visibility property and use this trigger instead.

```
    <Border>
        <Border.Style>
            <Style>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding XXXXX, Converter={StaticResource booleanConverter}}" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Border.Height" Value="0" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Border.Style>
    </Border>
```